# How to stop IE "moving" text around within a <div>?

Tags: internet-explorer

Humbly asking for help with (of course) IE.
I have a div that is a simple background color block (#greenback) and it contains two other divs.
The first (#billboard) is some centered text and the second (#picright) holds an image. They are arranged next to each other, text on left, image on right.

Looks ok in most FF etc but IE does weird things to the text div as follows:(the blue rectangle inside the green box shows the extent of the text div; teh image div is bordered in white.)

IE6 moves the text part-way out of bounds to the right of the text div so it overlaps the image.

[alt text http://www.conservationenterprises.com/staging/jan08/IE6.png](http://www.conservationenterprises.com/staging/jan08/IE6.png)

IE7 moves it part way out of bounds to the top of the text div.[alt text http://www.conservationenterprises.com/staging/jan08/IE7.png](http://www.conservationenterprises.com/staging/jan08/IE7.png)

IE8 at least keeps the text within the bounds of the div but ignores any within-div centering that I'm trying to achieve.

[alt text http://www.conservationenterprises.com/staging/jan08/IE8.png](http://www.conservationenterprises.com/staging/jan08/IE8.png)

I tried a holly hack on the text div but that doesn't seem to make any difference (or is that my placement of it in the css?).

Any help greatly appreciated...

Thanks, Patrick.

my css: (please don't laugh, it's still my first cobbled-together style sheet!)

```
#greenback { position: relative;
width: 800px ;
height: 250px ;
background-color: #7EBB11 ;
border: 3px solid #112D82 ;
}

#picright { position: relative ;
float: right;
display: block;
margin-top: 11px;
margin-right: 11px;
margin-bottom: 11px;
max-width: 50%;
max-height: 218px;
border: 3px solid white;
vertical-align: middle ;
}

#greenback>#billboard {/*display:table for Mozilla and Opera*/
display: table ;
position: static ;
}

#billboard  { /* for IE*/
width: 45% ;
height: 99% ;
background-color: #7EBB11 ;
font-family: Optima, Calibri, Candara, Century-Gothic, 
Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 160% ;
color: #ffffff ;    
position: relative; 
border: 2px solid blue;
}

#billboard div { /*for IE*/
position: absolute;
float: left ;
top: 50%;
}

#billboard>div { /*for Mozilla and Opera*/
display: table-cell ; 
vertical-align: middle ;
position: static;
}

#billboard div div {
position: relative ;
top: -50%;
}

/* Hides from IE5-mac \*/
* html .billboard {height: 1%;}
/* End hide from IE5-mac */
```

and my html:

```
<div id="greenback">
<img src="kids.jpg" alt="kids" id="picright" />
<div id="billboard"><div><div><p>We help businesses,<br>communities and nature<br>take better care<br>of each other.</p>
</div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the HTML it's hard to say but you shouldn't have `position: absolute` and `float: left` on the same element - that doesn't really make sense.

You probably shouldn't be using `position` anywhere in your stylesheet for this.  It's usually something to stay away from unless you're scripting.

Edit: give this a go:

```
<style>

#greenback {
    width: 800px ;
    height: 250px ;
    background-color: #7EBB11 ;
    border: 3px solid #112D82 ;
}

#picright {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    margin: 11px 11px 11px 20px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 218px;
    border: 3px solid white;
}

#billboard  {
    width: 45% ;
    height: 99% ;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    float: right;
}

#billboard p {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-family: Optima, Calibri, Candara, Century-Gothic, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 160% ;
    color: #ffffff ;
}
</style>

<div id="greenback">
    <img src="kids.jpg" alt="kids" id="picright" />
    <div id="billboard"><p>We help businesses,<br>communities and nature<br>take better care<br>of each other.</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that makes sense, thanks RoBorg.. the html is at the bottom of the posting under the css

Comment: Well, removing all the position statements didn't mess anything up in FF at least, let's see what happens with IE!

Comment: RoBorg, you are a legend! I'll buy you an e-beer for that (though they never taste as good...)  IE 6 and 7 both look like FF.  It's so good and so simple I'm in shock.  Still waiting on browsershots.org to render IE8. I wonder if this trick will work on other divs styling other pages on the site...

Comment: annakata, thanks so much for the edited code - it fixed my centering issue as well and it looks great on IE6,7 and 8 - and using the red line as a teaching tool is a beautiful touch. The page now looks great on IE6,7 and 8 too. Much appreciated.  This is such a nice forum. Now to the next divs..!